PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest how to configure the selection of a request option in one scenario
Question: How to implement the choice of an action option in one scenario? Is it possible to do this through a function and substitute only the necessary parameters when choosing an option?
There are remote devices that need to be backed up if necessary. There is a way to do this manually, after logging in, waiting for the GUI to fully load - it may take 5-10 minutes.
I wrote a CURL authorization request - it works. Then I did not bother with the command line, because there is a need to dodge, there is no necessary functionality. I rewrote it to PowerShell.
Step 1. Request authorization
$ip = Read-Host "Enter the ip address"

    $xmlauth = "<request method=""login"" request_id=""1"" username=""name"" password=""pass""/>"
    
    $access = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("http://"+$ip+":4000/xap2") `
        -Method Post `
        -ContentType "text/xml" `
        -Body $xmlauth
    $sessionid = ([xml]$access.Content).response.session_id
    Write-Host $access #example of output after successful authorization
    <response username="name" session_id="123456789" request_id="1" access_lvl="2">
      <status status="0" status_text="OK"/>
    </response>
    Write-Host $sessionid #this id is inserted in all subsequent requests
    123456789

Step 2. Request to change the parameters
$xml3in = @"
<request method="set" request_id="2" session_id="$sessionid" return_events="false">
  <data>
    <ports>
      <asi_input enable="false" _id="0"/>
      <asi_input enable="true" _id="2"/>
      <_all _id="8">
        <plprep main_globid="2"/>
      </_all>
    </ports>
  </data>
</request>
"@

$request3in = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("http://"+$ip+":4000/xap2") `
    -Method Post `
    -ContentType "text/xml" `
    -Body $xml3in
$status = ([xml]$request3in.Content).response.status.status_text
Write-Host $request3in #Example output after successful execution
<response request_id="2">
  <status status="0" status_text="OK"/>
</response>
Write-Host $status #An example of the output of the status text, you can also do it by number
OK    

if ( $status -like 'ok' ) {
    Write-Host "THE DEVICE IS SWITCHED WHERE IT IS NEEDED ($status)" -foregroundcolor Green
}
else {
    Write-Host "SOMETHING WENT WRONG ($status)" -foregroundcolor Red
}

Step 3. Request to change the parameters (return to the initial state)
The only difference is in the request body.
$xml1in = @"
<request method="set" request_id="3" session_id="$sessionid" return_events="false">
  <data>
    <ports>
      <asi_input enable="true" _id="0"/>
      <asi_input enable="false" _id="2"/>
      <_all _id="8">
        <plprep main_globid="0"/>
      </_all>
    </ports>
  </data>
</request>
"@

Update 10/28/24 Added menu. Now the function needs to be implemented in the menu selection options.
function askchoice {
Clear-Host
Write-Host "░░░░░ RESERVATION MENU ░░░░░" -backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░                          ░" -backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░ 1. ENTER IP ADDRESS      ░" -backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░ 2. TRANSFER TO 3in       ░" -backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░ 3. RETURN TO 1in         ░" -backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░ Q. EXIT                  ░" -backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░                          ░" -backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░" -backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "CURRENT STATION IP ADDRESS: $ip" -ForegroundColor Green
}

Do {
askchoice
$choice = Read-Host "SELECT NUMBER [1-3] OR Q TO LOG OUT"

switch ($choice)
{
        1 {
            $ban = @("10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11", "10.10.10.12", "10.10.10.13")
            do {
            $Global:ip = Read-Host "ENTER IP ADDRESS"
            if ($ban -contains $ip) {
            Write-Host "ACCESS DENIED" -ForegroundColor Red
            }
          }
          While ($ban -contains $ip)
        }
        2 {
            Write-Host "BACKUP PROCESS IN PROGRESS" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            #line of code
            ping $ip; pause
        }
        3 {
            Write-Host "RETURN TO STANDARD SCHEME IN PROCESS IN PROGRESS" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            #line of code
            tracert $ip; pause
        }
        q {
            exit
        }
        default {
                  Write-Host "NO NUMBER IN LIST, REPEAT SELECT" -ForegroundColor Yellow; pause
        }
    }
} 
while ($choice -ne "q")



Try increasing the Timeout (keep alive) which sends an empty TCP message so connection doesn't close.  WebRequest is HTTP which uses TCP for the Transport layer.  See https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/y8h36k/invokewebrequest_keepalive_timeout/

Yes you can pass multiple parameters to a function.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.4#functions-with-parameters

Just giving you a fancy way to convert and cURL to PS code. Check CURL to PS Converter

What's the problem with the current menu?

@MathiasR.Jessen : OP needs to pass parameters from menu to a function.  I provided a link yesterday to show how to pass parameters.

At the moment, this is the working design that has been achieved.
#Request body
$auth = [xml]"<request method=""login"" request_id=""1"" username=""name"" password=""pass""/>"
$backup = [xml]@"
<request method="set" request_id="2" session_id="" return_events="false">
    <data>
        <ports>
            <asi_input enable="false" _id="0"/>
            <asi_input enable="true" _id="2"/>
            <_all _id="8">
                <plprep main_globid="2"/>
            </_all>
        </ports>
    </data>
</request>
"@
$primary = [xml]@"
<request method="set" request_id="3" session_id="" return_events="false">
    <data>
        <ports>
            <asi_input enable="true" _id="0"/>
            <asi_input enable="false" _id="2"/>
            <_all _id="8">
                <plprep main_globid="0"/>
            </_all>
        </ports>
    </data>
</request>
"@
$check = [xml]@"
<request method="get" request_id="4" session_id="">
  <data>
    <ports>
      <_all _id="8">
        <plprep _select="main_globid"/>
      </_all>
    </ports>
  </data>
</request>
"@

#POST requests by URL + Body
function Select-Replacer
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [xml]$body
    )
    $ErrorActionPreference = "STOP"
    try
    {
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method Post -ContentType "text/xml" -Body $body
        Write-Host ("RESPONSE CODE - "+$response.StatusCode) -Foregroundcolor Green
        Write-Host ("CONNECTION - "+$response.StatusDescription) -Foregroundcolor Green
        $sessionid = ([xml] $response.Content).response.session_id
        #Write-Host ("session_id in function - "+$sessionid)
        $status = ([xml]$response.Content).response.status.status_text
        #Write-Host ("execution status in a function - "+$status)
        $asiout = ([xml]$response.Content).response.data.ports.asi_output.plprep.main_globid
        #Write-Host ("source id in function - "+$asiout)
    }
    catch
    {
        #$e = $Error[0].Exception
        $e = $_.Exception
        Write-Host ("ERROR - "+$e.Message) -Foregroundcolor Red
        $ecode = [int]$e.Response.StatusCode
            if ($ecode -eq 404)
            {
                Write-Host ("RESPONSE CODE - "+$e.Response.StatusCode.value__) -Foregroundcolor Red
                Write-Host ("NO CONNECTION - "+$e.Response.StatusDescription) -Foregroundcolor Red
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host ("RESPONSE CODE - "+$e.Response.StatusCode.value__) -ForegroundColor Yellow
                Write-Host ("SOMETHING WENT WRONG - "+$e.Response.StatusDescription) -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }
    }
    $ErrorActionPreference = "CONTINUE"
    Return @{"session"=$sessionid; "status"=$status; "source"=$asiout;}
}

#Menu with the ability to clear the console
function Ask-Choice
{
Clear-Host
Write-Host "░░░░  RESERVATION MENU  ░░░░" -Backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░                          ░" -Backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░ 1. ENTER IP ADDRESS      ░" -Backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░ 2. REGISTER NOW          ░" -Backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░ 3. SWITCH TO 3in         ░" -Backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░ 4. RETURN TO 1in         ░" -Backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░ 5. CHECK THE SCHEMA      ░" -Backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░ Q. QUIT                  ░" -Backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░                          ░" -Backgroundcolor DarkBlue
Write-Host "░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░" -Backgroundcolor DarkBlue
}

#Selecting an option and calling a function
Do
{
Ask-Choice
Write-Host "CURRENT STATION IP ADDRESS: $ip" -ForegroundColor Magenta
$choice = Read-Host "SELECT NUMBER [1-5] OR Q TO EXIT"
switch ($choice)
{
    1
    {
        $ban = @("10.10.10.10", "10.10.10.11", "10.10.10.13", "10.10.10.14", "10.10.10.15")
        do
        {
            $ip = Read-Host "ENTER IP ADDRESS"
            $ipregex = "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"
            $url = "http://{0}:8049/xap2" -f $ip
            #$url = ("http://"+$ip+":8049/xap2")
                if ($ban -contains $ip)
                {
                    Write-Host "WARNING: ACCESS DENIED" -ForegroundColor Red
                }
                elseif ($ip -notmatch $ipregex)
                {
                    Write-Host "WARNING: INCORRECT IP OR EMPTY VALUE" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
        }
        While (($ban -contains $ip) -or ($ip -notmatch $ipregex))
    }
    2
    {
        Write-Host "REGISTRATION PROCESS IN PROGRESS" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $result = Select-Replacer $url $auth
        $XMLbody = $backup, $primary, $check
        Foreach ($item in (Select-XML -Xml $XMLbody -XPath "//request"))
        {
            $item.node.session_id = "$($result.session)"
        }
        Write-Host ("Session_id number - "+$($result.session))
        Write-Host ("Execution status - "+$($result.status))
            if ($($result.status) -like 'ok')
            {
                Write-Host "SUCCESS" -ForegroundColor Green; pause
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "ERROR" -Foregroundcolor Red -Backgroundcolor White; pause
        }
        Clear-Variable -name result.status
    }
    3
    {
        Write-Host "THE RESERVATION PROCESS IS IN PROGRESS" -foregroundColor Cyan
        $result = Select-Replacer $url $backup
        Write-Host ("Execution status - "+$($result.status))
            if ($($result.status) -like 'ok')
            {
                Write-Host "SUCCESS" -ForegroundColor Green; pause
            }
            elseif ($($result.status) -like "Unknown session ID")
            {
                Write-Host "REQUIRED TO REGISTER" -Foregroundcolor Red -Backgroundcolor White; pause
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "ERROR" -Foregroundcolor Red -Backgroundcolor White; pause
        }
        Clear-Variable -name result.status
    }
    4
    {
        Write-Host "THE PROCESS OF RETURNING TO THE STANDARD SCHEME IS IN PROGRESS" -foregroundColor Cyan
        $result = Select-Replacer $url $primary
        Write-Host ("Execution status - "+$($result.status))
            if ($($result.status) -like 'ok')
            {
                Write-Host "SUCCESS" -ForegroundColor Green; pause
            }
            elseif ($($result.status) -like "Unknown session ID")
            {
                Write-Host "REQUIRED TO REGISTER" -Foregroundcolor Red -Backgroundcolor White; pause
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "ERROR" -Foregroundcolor Red -Backgroundcolor White; pause
        }
        Clear-Variable -name result.status
    }
    5
    {
        Write-Host "CHECKING THE CURRENT STATE OF THE SHEMA" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $result = Select-Replacer $url $check
        Write-Host ("Execution status - "+$($result.status))
        Write-Host ("This is the source id - "+$($result.source))
            if (($($result.status) -like 'ok') -and ($($result.source) -eq '0'))
            {
                Write-Host "PRIMARY SOURCE 1.in" -Foregroundcolor Yellow; pause
            }
            elseif (($($result.status) -like 'ok') -and ($($result.source) -eq '2'))
            {
                Write-Host "BACKUP SOURCE 3.in" -Foregroundcolor Green; pause
            }
            elseif ($($result.status) -like "Unknown session ID")
            {
                Write-Host "REQUIRED TO REGISTER" -Foregroundcolor Red -Backgroundcolor White; pause
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "ERROR" -Foregroundcolor Red -Backgroundcolor White; pause
        }
        Clear-Variable -name result.status
    }
    q
    {
        exit
    }
    default
    {
        Write-Host "THERE IS NO NUMBER IN THE LIST, REPEAT YOUR SELECTION" -ForegroundColor Yellow; pause
        }
    }
}
while ($choice -ne "q")

